# How to validate/process the Spring WebClient response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming

So the app flow is like:

1. Spring app receives the request -> {"id": "UUID"}
2. Calls the external web service using the WebClient
3. Validate the response received in step 2 from WebClient. Return true or false if validation passes.
4. Do other validations operations(via calling other processes or ext services) and send back the response to the user.

This is the webclient which I am using(replica):

```
public Mono<Details> someRestCall(String name) {
        return this.webClient.get().url("/{id}/details", name)
                        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Details.class);
    }
```

Now I don't want to return this Mono object directly to the client(like the Angular app) via the controller, since this is an intermediary step. I want to run few validations on the response received from the WebClient.

I have tried the `.block()` method to retrieve the function but it seems to be a bad practice as per the reactive programming. (blocking op)
Also, I am unable to understand how to use the `.subscribe()` method to retrieve the response object and run validation/checks on it and return `True` if the validation passes.

In simple terms, instead of returning a Mono object from my module/validation code, I want to return a normal boolean value/Java object.

I am new to reactive programming, can anyone please help me get this resolved?

Comment: No you don't. You want to return a `Mono<Boolean>` after the retrieve, call `map`, execute yourl ogic and return a `Mono<Boolean>`.

Comment: @m-deinum can you provide a code example for the same. I tried the .map thing but getting an error.

Comment: what have you tried, add it to your question.

Comment: Got it working, but still have one doubt hope you can help me out with that. How am I supposed to peek into the Mono<Boolean> and check the content to make some decisions, without blocking the thread?

Comment: Use `map`. What decision, what do you need to do? Does it influence the outcome?

Comment: Yes, I do validation check base don the WebClient output and as of now, I return Mono<boolean>. But on the basis of this Mono<Boolean> object I need to call other services if the value is true.

Comment: As mentioned, call `map` again and do something based on the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little effort you can use JSR-303 annotation based validation on the POJOs that are returned by a WebClient call. Here's a minimal example:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

  final Validator validator;

  MyClass(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  <T> T validate(T obj) {

    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = this.validator.validate(obj);
    if (violations.size() > 0) {
      throw new ResponseStatusException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, violations.toString());
    }

    return obj;
  }

  public Mono<Details> someRestCall(String name) {
    return this.webClient.get()
        .url("/{id}/details", name)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Details.class)
        .doOnNext(this::validate);
  }
}
```

In practice you might want a better formatted violations string and if validation is done in a few places then you could lift that logic into its own class.